# ora-24408 could not generate unique server group name in

Tags: php, oracle

**Solution:**

Go to terminal and type '*hostname*' to know you host name

**$ hostname**
Adam

**$ vi /etc/hosts**
add '*127.1.1.1 Adam*' to this file
Save

$ service apache2 restart

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks. It is nice that you like to add something to this site. But the quality of your posts need to be way better than this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to terminal and type 'hostname' to know you host name

$ hostname

Adam

$ vi /etc/hosts add '127.1.1.1 Adam' to this file Save

$ service apache2 restart

Hope it will help.